# I have no time to develop new one, how can i find a free JSF-webmail application?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jakarta-mail, webmail

I need a Mailing System in my local network, and actually i don't prefer now to spend time on developing new one, can anybody suggest me a free JSF web mail application. Knowing that i am using a local James-3 IMAP server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the [JavaMail Third Party Products page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html).

Answer (score 0):

[JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)? It is part of Java EE.

Comment: You misuderstood me, i can build a jsf application using JavaMail, that is clear. But i am seeking an already writen application in order not to spend time on reenventing the wheel

Comment: @primeFaceUser my bad then